# Chatham Islands Bounding Box issue in EPSG:4326 on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, epsg, antimeridian

I have vector layer published on GeoServer for New Zealand territory including Chatham Islands, that are close to Anti-Meridian line:

[image]

Layer is sourced from PostgreSQL DB, and it doesn't have specified projection there, this is the system need and can't be changed.

When it is published on GeoServer, Geoserver recognizes projection as 40400, which is a wildcard, and I assign declared CRS as EPSG:4326 since I need data in this EPSG.

[image]

I compute extent from data or enter manually taking it from Google Earth, or websites for BBox:

[image]

[image]

Then in this case in Layer Preview, I have objects visible only on the New Zealand territory and not islands around:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Only zooming out to the scale of 1:140M - makes objects on Chatham Islands to appear:

[image]

When I assign Declared CRS as EPSG:3758, With the following extent:
[image]

in this case all good. Objects are visible right away:

[image]

What is the correct bounding box for NZ and islands in EPSG:4326?

Comment: You need to store your data in a recognised projection that doesn't cross the anti-meridian, your max of 186 is invalid in epsg:4326, if you reproject it GeoServer will handle it

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, can you advice, please, which projection can be used in this case? On the database side, you mean, right? No way to setting specific bbox on GeoServer side only?

Comment: No, database is where to fix this. I can't really help with projections for that part of the world, since I live near Greenwich. Check what LINZ use?

Comment: Thank you a million! LINZ uses EPSG:4167. I've published this as a test from "Directory of shapefile": https://data.linz.govt.nz/layer/50839-nz-protected-survey-marks/ and it is reflected correctly.  
Can I set Declared SRS to 4326? How correctly select Native BBox and Lat/Long BBox in this case? Any option that I try makes islands disappear. Is it technically wrong to reproject from 4167 to 4326 on the fly by GeoServer itself?

Alternatively, can data be stores in epsg:4326 in the database or it is not suitable because it is intersected with antemeridian? Sorry for dozens of questions.

Comment: You need to set the layer CRS to be what the data is in. Then when you request the map in 4167 GeoServer will reproject it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Greatly appreciated!